# Shrink Parent Div to Foated Children

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a family tree and this last part of the functionality is giving me some difficulty.

My tree is a series of list elements that all are floated to the left.

What I'd like is that if the tree expands past the screen size the parent div #c1 should allow the user to scroll horizontally across the tree.

What is happening now is that if the tree has a width greater than #c1, then the tree wraps itself making it unreadable.

I've temporarily fixed this by adding a div inside #c1 called #c2, that has a width of 100000px. Basically the tree won't ever get this large so it'll never wrap in on itself, and the user can scroll across the tree.

What i'd like is to somehow fit the width of #c2 to the tree on loading with javascript, or somehow find a css solution to this.

I've tried using white-space: nowrap, and a lot of other solutions I've found to similar questions, however nothing seems to be working for me.

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.scrollbtn {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #ccc;

  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;

  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
}
.scrollbtn:hover {
  background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}

#c1 {
  width: 96%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 2%;

}

#c2 {
    width: 100000px;
}

.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px; position: relative;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
  float: left; text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%; height: 32px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.tree li::after{
  right: auto; left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}
.tree li li:only-child{ float: none;}
/*Remove left connector from first child and
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
  border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;

  -webkit-transform: translateX(1px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(1px);
  transform: translateX(1px);

  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: -12px; left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0; height: 32px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.tree li a{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;

  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.tree li a+a {
  margin-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.tree li a+a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  top: 47%; left: -21px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 6%;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover~ul li a {
  background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover~ul li::after,
.tree li a:hover~ul li::before,
.tree li a:hover~ul::before,
.tree li a:hover~ul ul::before
{
  border-color: #94a0b4;
}

a {
  width: 130px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tree.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="c1">
        <div id="c2">
          <div class="tree" id="tree"><ul><li><a href = "?Family=Haverlah&ID=43&Gen=5">Up Tree</a><ul><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=45&Gen=5">Rosa Haverlah</a><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=54&Gen=5">Charles Carl Schroeder</a><ul><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=55&Gen=5">William J. Schroeder</a><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=94&Gen=5">Pauline Stulken</a><ul><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=95&Gen=5">William J. Schroeder Jr.</a></li><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=96&Gen=5">Clarence Schroeder</a><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=216&Gen=5">Grace Nixon</a><ul><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=217&Gen=5">Marion Schroeder</a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=56&Gen=5">Rosalinda Schroeder</a><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=97&Gen=5">John Pfeil</a><ul><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=98&Gen=5">Esther Hertha Pfeil</a><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=218&Gen=5">Theodor Frederick Winter</a><ul><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=219&Gen=5">Florence Winter</a></li><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=220&Gen=5">Sandra Jean Winter</a></li></ul></li><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=221&Gen=5">William Goode</a><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=99&Gen=5">Edna Eltice Pfeil</a><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=222&Gen=5">Waldemar Otto Rehfeld</a></li><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=100&Gen=5">Walton James Pfeil</a></li><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=101&Gen=5">John Wallis Pfeil</a><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=228&Gen=5">Mae Jeanette Ermler</a><ul><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=229&Gen=5">Darrell Kent Pfeil</a></li><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=230&Gen=5">Paul Wallis Pfeil</a></li><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=231&Gen=5">Leona Rose Pfeil</a></li><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=232&Gen=5">Julie Gay Pfeil</a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=57&Gen=5">Charles William Schroeder</a><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=102&Gen=5">Natalie Brinkoeter</a><ul><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=103&Gen=5">Charles Astor Schroeder</a><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=233&Gen=5">Sue Rose Jones</a></li></ul></li><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=58&Gen=5">G. Adolph Schroeder</a><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=104&Gen=5">Helen Stribeck</a><ul><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=105&Gen=5">Lorena Schroeder</a></li><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=106&Gen=5">Helen Schroeder</a></li><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=107&Gen=5">Glen Schroeder</a></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></div>        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure CSS solution, if you're not attached to floats (which may be creating other difficulties for you - since a parent element with only floated children will have a collapsed content box, your #c2 div had a height of 0 and its content was "hanging out the bottom").

3 steps in your CSS:

1. Remove

   ```
   #c2 {
       width: 100000px;
   }
   ```

   (You can take the #c2 div out of your HTML altogether)
2. Add

   ```
   .tree {
       white-space: nowrap;
   }
   ```
3. Change the rules in your `.tree li` selector to make that code block look like this:

   ```
   .tree li {
       display: inline-block;
       vertical-align: top;
       text-align: center;
       list-style-type: none;
       position: relative;
       padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
       -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
       -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
       transition: all 0.5s;
   }
   ```

This will use `display: inline-block` to put the pieces of your tree next to each other horizontally, `vertical-align: top` to keep them vertically aligned to the top of their container, and `white-space: nowrap` on their container to make sure they don't flow over onto new lines. Note that it is important to keep `overflow: auto` on your div #c1, or else put `overflow-x: scroll` onto the div #tree, to enable the horizontal scrolling behavior you wanted.

Working snippet below:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.scrollbtn {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #ccc;

  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;

  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
}
.scrollbtn:hover {
  background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}

#c1 {
  width: 96%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 2%;

}

/*modified*/
#c2 {
    width: auto;
}

/*modified*/
.tree {
 /*overflow-x: scroll;*/
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px; position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*modified*/
.tree li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%; height: 32px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.tree li::after{
  right: auto; left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}
.tree li li:only-child{ float: none;}
/*Remove left connector from first child and
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
  border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;

  -webkit-transform: translateX(1px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(1px);
  transform: translateX(1px);

  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: -12px; left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0; height: 32px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.tree li a{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;

  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.tree li a+a {
  margin-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.tree li a+a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  top: 47%; left: -21px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 6%;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover~ul li a {
  background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover~ul li::after,
.tree li a:hover~ul li::before,
.tree li a:hover~ul::before,
.tree li a:hover~ul ul::before
{
  border-color: #94a0b4;
}

a {
  width: 130px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
  <title>fiddle</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tree.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="c1">
        <div id="c2">
          <div class="tree" id="tree"><ul><li><a href = "?Family=Haverlah&ID=43&Gen=5">Up Tree</a><ul><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=45&Gen=5">Rosa Haverlah</a><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=54&Gen=5">Charles Carl Schroeder</a><ul><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=55&Gen=5">William J. Schroeder</a><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=94&Gen=5">Pauline Stulken</a><ul><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=95&Gen=5">William J. Schroeder Jr.</a></li><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=96&Gen=5">Clarence Schroeder</a><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=216&Gen=5">Grace Nixon</a><ul><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=217&Gen=5">Marion Schroeder</a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=56&Gen=5">Rosalinda Schroeder</a><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=97&Gen=5">John Pfeil</a><ul><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=98&Gen=5">Esther Hertha Pfeil</a><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=218&Gen=5">Theodor Frederick Winter</a><ul><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=219&Gen=5">Florence Winter</a></li><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=220&Gen=5">Sandra Jean Winter</a></li></ul></li><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=221&Gen=5">William Goode</a><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=99&Gen=5">Edna Eltice Pfeil</a><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=222&Gen=5">Waldemar Otto Rehfeld</a></li><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=100&Gen=5">Walton James Pfeil</a></li><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=101&Gen=5">John Wallis Pfeil</a><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=228&Gen=5">Mae Jeanette Ermler</a><ul><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=229&Gen=5">Darrell Kent Pfeil</a></li><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=230&Gen=5">Paul Wallis Pfeil</a></li><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=231&Gen=5">Leona Rose Pfeil</a></li><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=232&Gen=5">Julie Gay Pfeil</a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=57&Gen=5">Charles William Schroeder</a><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=102&Gen=5">Natalie Brinkoeter</a><ul><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=103&Gen=5">Charles Astor Schroeder</a><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=233&Gen=5">Sue Rose Jones</a></li></ul></li><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=58&Gen=5">G. Adolph Schroeder</a><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=104&Gen=5">Helen Stribeck</a><ul><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=105&Gen=5">Lorena Schroeder</a></li><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=106&Gen=5">Helen Schroeder</a></li><li><a href = "info.php?Family=Haverlah&ID=107&Gen=5">Glen Schroeder</a></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></div>        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
 </body>
</html>
```